# Display table count in html

Tags: php, mysqli

I trying to create the backend for a booking system and need to show all booked appointments on each date for each location. My appointments table looks like this:

```
id, booked_date, location_id, customer_id
```

and I would like to display this in a html table like this:

|  | Date 1 | Date 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Location 1 Name | Number of booked appointments | Number of booked appointments |
| Location 2 Name | Number of booked appointments | Number of booked appointments |

I have a separate table of Locations that has full details like and and address.

I also have a table of event dates (id, start_date)

Im struggling to comprehend what I need to do here!

EDIT:

I just need some help putting everything together into the example table above.

Database tables : appointments, locations, event_dates

I have this query and the function below - `SELECT t1.location_id, t1.start_datetime, t2.name, COUNT(*) AS count FROM appointment t1 INNER JOIN location t2 ON t1.location_id = t2.id GROUP BY t1.location_id, t1.start_datetime`

```
    function countAppointment() {
    
      require 'config.php';
    
    $sql = "SELECT t1.location_id, t1.start_datetime, t2.name, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM appointment t1
    INNER JOIN location t2
    ON t1.location_id = t2.id
    GROUP BY t1.location_id, t1.start_datetime";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    
          $a1 = $row['start_datetime'];
          $a2 = $row['location_id'];
          $a3 = $row['name'];
          $a4 = $row['count'];
    
          //echo "$a1 <br> $a2 <br> $a3 <br> $a4 <br><br>";
    
          echo "<tr><th scope='row'>$a3</th>";
          echo "<td><a href='#'>$a4</a></td>";
          echo "<td>9</td><td>27</td><td>14</td></tr>";
    
      }
    } else {
       return "0";
    }

$conn->close();
}
```

Comment: You need to write a PHP function which returns the markup for an HTML `<table>`  where the cells (`<td>`) in each row (`<tr>`) are populated with the data it retrieves from your database.

Comment: Hi Kevin, can you post what you have tried so far? Also, I'm guessing there are database calls and a database table structure, without any insight into these, it is difficult to help you.

Comment: Add some more info, do you know how to get the data from the table? If not, may I suggest you do some reading into [MySQL's SELECT statements](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_select.asp) and [PHP's mysqli library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: @Ant I know how to get the data from the table. Its just displaying it like the example above that im struggling with.

Comment: @Clint I have added some info.

Comment: @Ant I have updated the function. I just need some help getting the output to display like the example table above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");

// Check connection
if ($con -> connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $con -> connect_error;
  exit();
}
$data = array();
$date_list= array();
$sql_date_list ="SELECT start_datetime from appointment GROUP BY start_datetime";
$result_date_list = mysqli_query($con, $sql_date_list); 
$sql_loc_list = "SELECT `name` FROM `location` GROUP BY `name`";
$result_loc_list = mysqli_query($con, $sql_loc_list); 
$k=0;
while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_loc_list)){
    $data +=[$row['name']=>array()];
    if($k==0){
        while($row2 =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_date_list)){
            array_push($date_list,$row2['start_datetime']);
            $data[$row['name']]+=[$row2['start_datetime']=>0];
        }
        $k++;
    }else{
        foreach($date_list as $date){
            $data[$row['name']]+=[$date=>0];
        }
    }
}

$sql_getdata = "SELECT t2.name as loc_name, t1.start_datetime, COUNT(t1.location_id) AS count FROM appointment t1 JOIN location t2 ON t1.location_id = t2.id GROUP BY t1.location_id,t1.start_datetime"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql_getdata); 
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $data[$row['loc_name']][$row['start_datetime']]=$row['count'];
}
$table="<table border='1'>";
$table.="<tr>";
$table.="<th>location</th>";
foreach ($date_list as $date) {
    $table.="<th>".$date."</th>";
}
$table.="</tr>";
foreach ($data as $key=>$date) {
    $table.="<tr>";
    $table.="<td>".$key."</td>";
        foreach($date as $key2=>$count){
            $table.="<td>".$count."</td>";
        }
    $table.="</tr>";
}

$table.="<table>";
echo $table;
?>
```

output
[image: output]

Comment: Its almost perfect, however because the start_datetime field for me is a date and time, your code counts each unique date time combination as a header, when it should only be  doing it for the date.

Comment: I added a new column to my table of just the date and changed references from start_datetime to start_date and it works now.

Comment: If I wanted to change this $table.="<td>".$count."</td>"; to $table.="<td><a href=appointments-by-day?id=".$location_id.">".$count."</a></td>"; How would I get the location ID?

Comment: @kevin you can add lacation_id to $sql_getdata quary and use it in while loop